# ProcessBuilder: Git repository does not download

Tags: java, git, github

I'm using ProcessBuilder to download from Git. This is my current code:

```
Process process = null;
try {
    String[] command = {"git", "clone", gitLink};
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    processBuilder.directory(new File(gitPath));
    process = processBuilder.start();

    System.out.println("\n*** Console output is:");
    InputStream processStdOutput = process.getInputStream();
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(processStdOutput);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { System.out.println("\t" + line); }

    process.getOutputStream().close();
} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
finally { if (process != null) { process.destroy(); } }
```

So, `gitLink` would be an actual link to the repository I want to download, and `gitPath` is where it will be downloaded to on my PC. `gitPath` seems to work, as I tested it by executing command `ls`. `gitLink`, however, shows up nothing. I get the Git repository for a second (in the correct `gitPath` folder), and then it vanishes. Also, when I use the actual link for Git repository instead of the variable `gitLink`, it works perfectly. For some reason it doesn't like the variable gitLink.

That's the code that works:

```
String[] command = {"git", "clone", "https://some-rep.git"};
```

Other things beng equal.

Comment: So print the command before you execute it. If it's not the same as the one that works, then there is the problem. If it is the same as the one that works, then the problem isn't in your java code but elsewhere .

Comment: Okay, just figured the issue... Apparently, extra spaces at the end of the link are not treated well by ProcessBuilder. 

Thx tho!