# How to run long command in ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, terminal, processbuilder

I am trying to use this command:

```
git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --before="2009-07-27 13:37" master`
```

Which I am running through ProcessBuilder. Now, I know that the rest of my code works, as I have tested it with other examples. But I am not sure how to split this command so that it works for ProcessBuilder.

Apparently, this method did not work:

```
String[] command = {"git", "checkout", "`git rev-list -n 1 --before=\"2014-01-01 12:00\" master`"};
```

This did not work as well:

```
String[] command = {"git", "checkout", "`git", "rev-list", "-n", "1", "--before=\"2014-01-01 12:00\"", "master`"};
```

I am also not getting any output from the console (I do InputStream), which means it's harder for me to figure out what's the issue. I am thinking the problem should be obvious to people familiar enough with ProcessBuilders, so yeah...

The rest of my code looks as such:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
processBuilder.directory(new File(fullPath));
process = processBuilder.start();
```

And the path for the directory should be correct as I checked it (it is inside of the main directory of the repository).

If by any chance I need to provide other parts of the code, I will.

Comment: Quick answer is that you need to run `git rev-list...` command first using `ProcessBuilder` capture its output and pass it as arguments to your `git checkout` command. I will followup with a long answer :)

Comment: Thanks, it works! I will still read your full response, once you write it. I need to figure out how to use ProcessBuilder twice in a row.

Comment: Back-quotes are only understood by a shell like bash.  Java (like C) runs the commands directly, without using any shell, so back-quotes (and all other quotes, and also redirection symbols) are not special in any way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProcessBuilder: Git repository does not download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248000/processbuilder-git-repository-does-not-download)

Comment: No, I had a slightly different issue there. In the other post, my problem was that ProcessBuilder or the command I was using did not like extra spaces at the end of the string. In this post, I was asking how to use recurrent git functions in the ProcessBuilder. As I am new to the StackOverflow community, I am not deleting my posts in case someone has similar issues. However, if this implies that people will be looking at my posts to answer them, then I should probably delete the solved cases to not attract additional attention and waste someone's time.

Answer (score 2):

The back-ticks are actually handled by the unix shell - Java doesn't process them. When using process builder you should execute the command given in the back-ticks and pass the output as parameters to the second command. A simple example is below: (using 'ls').

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class ProcessBuilderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Command: ls `ls /etc/passwd /etc/services`

        // Read the output from the command second ls...
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ls", "/etc/passwd", "/etc/services");
        Process process = pb.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(is, Charset.defaultCharset());

        ArrayList<String> cmdParts = new ArrayList<>();
        cmdParts.add("ls");
        cmdParts.addAll(lines);

        // Construct the second command
        ProcessBuilder pbLs = new ProcessBuilder(cmdParts);
        Process lsProcess = pbLs.start();
        System.out.println(IOUtils.readLines(lsProcess.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
        lsProcess.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be easier to use `String[] command = {"bash", "-c", "git checkout \`git rev-list -n 1 --before=\"2014-01-01 12:00\" master\`"};`? Or are there any disadvanatges of this method against the one you proposed?

Comment: Only couple of issues. 1. Once you use it is more or less Unix only 2. One extra process. Otherwise it is OK.